# Power BI inactive relationships

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an active relationship between table A and B that can’t be deactivated. Now, I have a inactive relationship between the same two table and I need to use this relationship as a filter for both. What can I do?

I have tried everything and I always manage to filter only one table.

Thanks everyone in advance 
Ed

Comment: have you tried DAX function "USERELASHIONSHIP"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate both column of each table on which relations can be created and create a new relationship  on this newly created column this will help u to filter the report using both the columns 
Eg:- Table 1 - Relation ship columns are  C1 and C2
Table 2 - Relationship column are C3 and C4

create a new column in table 1 say RC1 using dax  Concatenate(c1,c2) and in table 2  say RC2 using
Concatenate(c3,c4) now create a realtionship on RC1 and RC2 (both side relationship)